# Decoding ID from service

Tags: base64

I am trying to determine if there is any information contained in an ID I get from a service. The ID is like so:

> CAAqOQgKIjNDQklTSURvSmMzUnZjbmt0TXpZd1NoTUtFUWl2MXVPWmtZQU1FUnJUdlc4dFNBaWpLQUFQAQ

When I run this through a base64 decode I get the following:

> *9
> "3CBISIDoJc3RvcnktMzYwShMKEQiv1uOZkYAMERrTvW8tSAijKAAP

However I am not sure if I can go further with this. Does this look an encoding anyone recognises?

Comment: I noticed that 3CBISIDoJc3RvcnktMzYwShMKEQiv1uOZkYAMERrTvW8tSAijKAAP has the same lenght as salt+hash in bcrypt password

Comment: That might explain why the ID is sometimes slightly different yet points to the same resource